# How can I have two labels for a toggle switch?

Tags: python, toggle, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

How can I have two labels for a toggle button in Plotly Dash? Or a different kind of button with two labels. 
[image]

In the picture above, the 'Toggle here for XX' are the labels. Currently, its defined as:

```
dbc.Col(dbc.NavbarBrand("Toggle here for A")),
dbc.Col(
        daq.ToggleSwitch(
                         id='my-toggle-switch',
                         value=False
           )
),
dbc.Col(
        dbc.NavbarBrand("Toggle here for B") 
)
```

I need some different kind of button which will hold two labels to toggle.